# What does “pass around the house” mean?

Tags: meaning

The product description of [a (computer) tablet](https://www.argos.co.uk/product/8736352) reads,

> This is one tablet you'll want to **pass around the house**.

What does "pass around the house" mean here?
Does it mean that it's good enough to want to have even after giving the other person a house?

I searched dictionaries but couldn't find a relevant result.

Comment: You will want to pass (hand) it to other members of your household.

Comment: To *pass around* is to share. The *house* is your family. You don't need a dictionary before stopping by here, just Google stuff.

Comment: Another thing you can _pass around the house_ is bacteria and virus.

Comment: And 'around the house' is sometimes broadened (as with 'around the shop' in the UK) to mean 'all over'.